# Prolog query :- true, fail; not true, not fail; true, not fail

Tags: prolog

I am solving a test for an exam and I got this question with the following answers:

- fail
- yes
- true
- no

Running it in the shell i get True, but i cannot understand how this answer is obtained.
I get the first part `true, fail;`but the rest is a mistery.
Am i supposed to look just at the last part `true, not fail`?

Comment: Have you tried using `trace/0`. It will give you some idea of how that query is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
true, fail; not true, not fail; true, not fail
```

Can be translated into the following logical expression:

```
(true and false) or (((not true) and (not false)) or (true and (not false)))
```

That we can simplify progressively...

```
(true and false) or ((false and true) or (true and true))

false or (false or true)

false or true

true
```